# Binary classification of dated documents with seasonal class variation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, regression, document-classification

I have a collection of training documents with publication dates, where each document is labeled as belonging (or not) to some topic T. I want to train a model that will predict for a new document (with publication date) whether or not it belongs to T, where the publication date might be in the past or in the future. Assume that I have decomposed each training document's text into a set of features (e.g., TF-IDF of words or n-grams) suitable for analysis by an appropriate binary classification algorithm provided by a library like Weka (for instance, multinomial naive Bayes, random forests, or SVM). The concept to be learned exhibits multiple seasonality; i.e., the prior probability that an arbitrary document published on a given date belongs to T depends heavily on when the date falls in a 4-year cycle (due to elections), where it falls in an annual cycle (due to holidays), and on the day of the week.

My research indicates that classification algorithms generally assume (as part of their statistical models) that training data is randomly sampled from the same pool of data that the model will ultimately be applied to. When the distribution of classes in the training data differs substantially from the known distribution in the wild, this leads to the so-called "class imbalance" problem. There are ways of compensating for this, including over-sampling underrepresented classes, under-sampling overrepresented classes, and using cost-sensitive classification. This allows a model creator to implicitly specify the prior probability that a new document will be positively classified, but importantly (and unfortunately for my purposes), this prior probability is assumed to be equal for all new documents.

I require more flexibility in my model. Because of the concept's seasonality, when classifying a new document, the model must explicitly take the publication date into account when determining the prior probability that the document belongs to T, and when the model calculates the posterior probability of belonging to T in light of the document's features, this prior probability should be properly accounted for. I am looking for a classifier implementation that either (1) bakes sophisticated regression of prior probabilities based on dates into the classifier, or (2) can be extended with a user-specified regression function that takes a date as input and gives the prior probability as output.

I am most familiar with the Weka library, but am open to using other tools if they are appropriate to the job. What is the most straightforward way of accomplishing this task?

**Edit** (in response to Doxav's point #2):

My concern is that date-based attributes should not be used for learning rules about when the topic applies, rather, they should be used only for determining the prior probability of whether the topic applies. Here's a concrete example: suppose that the topic T is "Christmas". A story published in July is indeed much less likely to be about Christmas than a story published in December. But what makes a story about Christmas is the textual content of the story, not when it was published. The relationship between publication date and "being about Christmas" is mere correlation, and therefore only useful for calculating the prior probability of an arbitrary story on an arbitrary date being about Christmas. By comparison, the relationship between TF-IDF (for some term in the story text) and "being about Christmas" is inherent and causative, and therefore worthy of incorporation into our model of what it means for a story to be about Christmas.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it can be simplified into typical ML problems: text classification + imbalanced data  + seasonality identification + architecture + typical batch/offline vs stream/online learning :

1. Text classification: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY29uC4uem8 is a good tutorial on text classification with Weka and covers imbalance data issue.
2. Seasonality identification: the goal is to enable the model to learn rules/inference on some different time attributes, so we should ease its job by extracting best known useful attributes. It means extracting typical date cycles (ie. week day, day of month, month, year...) and, if possible, also merge it with other more specific cycles or events (ie. elections, holidays, any custom cycle or frequent event). If you expect the model to learn on time series/sequences, you should create some lag data (attributes who happened before or statistics on recent time interval). It can be good to remove the date itself or any data which would make biase the model construction.
3. I don't know if you plan to deliver this as a service, but this can be of good inspiration: http://fr.slideshare.net/TraianRebedea/autonomous-news-clustering-and-classification-for-an-intelligent-web-portal .
4. Typical batch/offline vs Stream / online learning: Apparently you already know Weka which focuses on batch/offline learning. I don't know the size of your data and if you plan to continuously process new data and rebuild models, then you could consider moving to stream processing and online learning. Therefore, you could move to MOA which is very close to Weka but dedicated to stream classification, or use new streaming features of the latest version of Weka (steam processing and new online learners).

UPDATE 1 ; I read your comment and I see different solutions:

- answer #2 is still one possible solution for your need even if it is not optimal. Getting an attribute indicating it's Christmas period will set an higher probability to tag it as a Christmas topic, same for the TF-IDF of the "word" Chritmas, BUT only both attributes together will set the max classification prob very highly to be Christmas.
- you can use an attribute providing a seasonal weight for each word: TF-IDF with time weight, or use current Google Trends data for each word.
- if you want a state of the art adaptive prior upon context you could look into hierarchical Bayesian models and smoothing from NLP solutions. It won't be Weka then and not as fast to test.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I edited my question to reflect my concerns about your point #2.